# How to edit content with two :before elements

Tags: css

I use a very complex CSS code just to add some basic content with a :before element. I have two .bold_help_text elements and I want to add different contents before each of these different divs.

I want the "ONLY $5.00" to be changed to different prices the first and second time it appears.

I don't know how to target the number one div or the number two div.

This is my current code:

### CSS:

```
.bold_option_checkbox span.bold_help_text:first-of-type>small:before {
  content: 'ONE TIME OFFER - ONLY $5.00';
color: #cc3300;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; !important; 
  }
```

This html code is used 2 times but different text content
1st time:

### HTML:

```
<div class="bold_option bold_option_checkbox ">
    <label>
     <span class="bold_option_element"></span>
      <span class="bold_option_title">Yes, I want to add my name!</span>
     </label>
    <span class="bold_help_text"><small>Text Content</small></span>
</div>
```

2st time:

```
<div class="bold_option bold_option_checkbox ">
    <label>
         <span class="bold_option_element"></span>
          <span class="bold_option_title">Yes, I want Envision Leggings 50% OFF!</span>
     </label>
 <span class="bold_help_text"><small>Text Content</small></span>
</div>
```

Here are two examples of different elements.
[First element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obsX9.png) [Secound element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfPLF.png)

Answer (score 0):

use `:first-child` selector with `.bold_option_checkbox`

```css
.bold_option_checkbox span.bold_help_text:first-of-type>small:before {
  content: 'ONE TIME OFFER - ONLY $5.00';
  color: #cc3300;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.bold_option_checkbox:first-child span.bold_help_text:first-of-type>small:before {
  content: 'ONE TIME OFFER - ONLY $10.00';
}
```

```html
<div class="bold_option bold_option_checkbox ">
  <label>
     <span class="bold_option_element"></span>
      <span class="bold_option_title">Yes, I want to add my name!</span>
     </label>
  <span class="bold_help_text"><small>Text Content</small></span>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div class="bold_option bold_option_checkbox ">
  <label>
         <span class="bold_option_element"></span>
          <span class="bold_option_title">Yes, I want Envision Leggings 50% OFF!</span>
     </label>
  <span class="bold_help_text"><small>Text Content</small></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this code and the :first-child content will popup at both places. So it still did not work :S

Comment: @KalleFeldt Let me clear this. Are you trying to say that this is not you wanted or this code snippet is working here (SO) but not in your project?

Comment: this solution works. @KalleFeldt are you looking for something else?